# No muestra la fecha

Tags: php, mysql, modal, fullcalendar, datetimepicker

Estoy implementando un calendario del tipo datetimepicker,  después de batallar un poco para que lograra funcionar o mostrarlo , ahora tengo el inconveniente que no me muestra la fecha que se carga desde la base de datos,  en lugar de eso me muestra la fecha actual, y yo necesito que me muestre la fecha que se tiene almacenada en la base de datos.

El datetimepicker esta montando sobre un calendario Fullcalendar para modificar las fechas de la programación de tareas.

```js
$("#startEdit").datetimepicker({
                            startDate:new Date("startEdit"),
                            startDate: "startEdit",
                            minDate:"-startEdit",
                            format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss",
                            timepicker:false
                        });
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="startEdit" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha Inicial</label>
                            <div class="input-group date" id="startEdit">
                                <input type="text"  id="startEdit" name="startEdit" value=""  class="form-control" readonly/>
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

los datos que se muestran en el calendario (fullcalendar) se consultan mediante consulta, se tiene la vista y los datos cargados en una serie de variables y al momento de hacer doble clic se trasladan a un modal que es donde se estaría llevando a cabo a modificación de las tareas, quien elabora la tarea y las fechas dispuestas para ello,  los datos se trasladan de la siguiente manera:

```html
eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.bind('dblclick', function() {

                $('#ModalEditarEvento #IdEdit').val(event.id);
                $('#ModalEditarEvento #ActividadesEdit').val(event.actividad);
                $('#ModalEditarEvento #PersonalEdit').val(event.personal);
                $('#ModalEditarEvento #UnidadesEdit').val(event.unidad);
                $("#ModalEditarEvento #startEdit").val(moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
                $("#ModalEditarEvento #endEdit").val(moment(end).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
                $('#ModalEditarEvento').modal('show');
            });
        },
```

El único detalle es que no me carga la fecha registrada en la base de datos, o la que tiene almacenada en la variable, me toma la fecha actual por default.

Se agradece cualquier aportación

Saludos

Adelantando un cambio :

Estuve checando el código y note una instrucción así que decidí cambiar esa instrucción  la linea original es esta:`$("#ModalEditarEvento #startEdit").val(moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));`  y pensé que si cambiaba un poco esa linea a:`$("#ModalEditarEvento #startEdit").val(event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));` que efecto tendria, y bueno les puedo anticipar que en el input donde muestra la fecha esta cambio a la fecha que se tiene almacenada en la variable.   Lo que todavia no encuentro es como hacer que esa fecha se muestre en la vista del datepicker ya que siempre muestra la fecha actual.

Saludos

Comment: No estoy seguro de que Datetimepicker usas, pero lo normal es llamar al "plugin" y darle el valor. Podes probar así `$('#startEdit').data('DateTimePicker').date([fecha-formateada])`